# Pattern sequence in Google Sheets

Tags: sequence, google-sheets-formula

I have a pattern sequence (car, apple, chair). I want it to be inserted "n" times in other column, ¿how could I make it with a formula?

Colors don't matter, I just want to repeat the text patern (car, apple, chair, car, apple, chair...)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this formula in your cell `G2`, it will automatically add both columns `G` and `H`:

`={sequence(H1),TRANSPOSE(split(rept(join(";",A2:A)&";",H1/counta(A2:A)),";"))}`

with formatting:

```
={
  sequence(H1),
  TRANSPOSE(
    split(
      rept(
        join(";",A2:A)&";",
        H1/counta(A2:A)
      ),
    ";")
  )
 }
```

If you just want the formula to the `H` column then here it is:

`=TRANSPOSE(split(rept(join(";",A2:A)&";",H1/counta(A2:A)),";"))`

[image]